# Solution to Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

> Which of the following is a solution of $u(x) = x + \int_{0}^{x} (t-x)u(t)dt$??
>
> (A) $\sin x$
>
> (B) $x \cos x$
>
> (C) $\ln (x+1)$
>
> (D) $x e^{-x}$
>
> (E) $xe^x$

Since all of the choices are twice differentiable, the first thing that came to mind my was to differentiate and then use Leibniz' rule; then differentiate again and then use the FTOC. Doing this gave me $\frac{u''(x)}{u(x)} = x-1$, but I don't remember how to solve differential equations. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Also, what is the more orthodox way of solving this? Keep in mind that this is a practice problem for the GRE, so it has to be done within two minutes, which is rather absurd in my estimation.

I also realized, after having already typed this up, that none of the choices appear to satisfy the differential equation. What is wrong with my method? I probably made a stupid calculation error, which I fear I may do quite a lot on the GRE (I hate these sorts of tests...)

EDIT: Here is my calculation. First, the partial with respect to $x$ of the integrand is  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} tu(t) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x u(t) = - u(t)$. Taking the first derivative, we get

$$u'(x) = 1  + (x-x)u(x) + \int_{0}^{x} (-u(t))dt= 1 - \int_{0}^{x} u(t)dt$$

Hence the second derivative is

$$u''(x) = -u(x)$$.

Comment: Btw, how did you get $u''/u=x-1$?  If you laid out your steps, we'd probably be able to find where you went wrong...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I got it by making a stupid mistake, hardly unexpected. I did it again, but this time I got $u''(x)=-u(x)$, which is slightly different than what you got. Let me edit my post to include my work.

Comment: Oh, whoops, that enlightens me on my own errors (noting the problem has $(t-x)$ in the integral rather than $(x-t)$ as in Cauchy's formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quicker kill, with initial condition $u(0) = 0$: the Laplace transform.

Transforming both sides yields

$$ U(s) = \frac{1}{s^2} - \frac{U(s)}{s^2} $$

(I rewrote the integral as $-\int_0 ^x u(t)(x-t) \ dt $ to properly use the convolution formula.)

Now, rearrange to get

$$ U(s) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{s^2} \right) = \frac{1}{s^2} $$

and some division gives

$$ U(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} $$

giving the desired solution $u(x) = \sin x$.

Comment: Okay. I took the Laplace transformation of both sides, but I am having trouble showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{x} (t-x)u(t)dt \right) e^{-sx}dx$ equals $\frac{U(s)}{s^2}$. How did you arrive at this?

Comment: Try proving the convolution theorem for arbitrary functions. Start by changing the order of integration and then changing variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you had applied [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), you could've differentiated the integral more easily, giving

$$u''(x)=-u(x)$$

Since

$$\int_0^x(x-t)u(t)~\mathrm dt=\int_0^x\int_0^\sigma u(t)~\mathrm dt~\mathrm d\sigma$$

And it is obvious then that A is the correct answer.

Comment: One last thing: As you may have noticed, my solution hinged on the assumption that $u$ is twice differentiable. Is there a way around this assumption? For the sake of the blasted GRE, it's 'okay' to assume this, but for my own sake I would like to know how to make this argument more rigorous.

Comment: In order for the right hand side to make sense, you should assume that $u$ is at least locally integrable. Then the right hand side is continuous, which implies $u$ is continuous. That, in turn, implies the right hand side is differentiable, which implies $u$ is differentiable. So differentiating yields $u' = 1 - \int_0^{x}u(t)\, dt$, and since the right hand side is differentiable, $u$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: @user193319 See what Alex just said...